# Mockito verify a method is called onces after spy though it is never call

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a unit test and find a strange problem in the very beginning

```
    GSLClient gslClient = spy(new GSLSolaceClient());
    String orgId = "10006";
    int orgFlag = Destination.ORG_ID_INPUT_FLAG_APP;
    String eventId = "11010000";
    String scenario = "01";
    String inputDCN = "A00";
    String GSLRetDCN = "FT0";

    //mock
    when(gslClient.requestTargetDCNFromGSLServer(mockGSLBizSeqNo,orgId, eventId, scenario, orgFlag))
            .thenReturn(buildMockSuccessGSLRespMsg(GSLResponse.ORG_FALG_GSL_INPUT, GSLRetDCN))//success for first time
            .thenThrow(new GSLClient.GSLInvokeTimeoutException("Mock GSL timeout"));//timout for the second time

    verify(gslClient, never()).requestTargetDCNFromGSLServer(mockGSLBizSeqNo,orgId, eventId, scenario, orgFlag);
```

I have done nothing except mocking my object and then I verify that the mock method is never invoked.

But the result gives me :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked: 
gSLSolaceClient.requestTargetDCNFromGSLServer(
    "MOCKGSLBIZSEQNO_GSL_CACHE_TEST",
    "10006",
    "11010000",
    "01",
    0
);
Never wanted here:
-> at cn.webank.rmb.gsl.GSLCacheTest.test_76789232(GSLCacheTest.java:226)
But invoked here:
-> at cn.webank.rmb.gsl.GSLCacheTest.test_76789232(GSLCacheTest.java:222)


    at cn.webank.rmb.gsl.GSLCacheTest.test_76789232(GSLCacheTest.java:226)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I wonder if there any other places that call this method so I try removing the code

```
        when(gslClient.requestTargetDCNFromGSLServer(mockGSLBizSeqNo,orgId, eventId, scenario, orgFlag))
            .thenReturn(buildMockSuccessGSLRespMsg(GSLResponse.ORG_FALG_GSL_INPUT, GSLRetDCN))//success for first time
            .thenThrow(new GSLClient.GSLInvokeTimeoutException("Mock GSL timeout"));//timout for the second time
```

Then the result is passed, proving that actually no other place is calling this method.

But Why does mockito give me this result?

I have tried the below test but it pass!

```
   {
        //test mock
        Date mockD = spy(new Date());
        when(mockD.getTime())
                .thenReturn(1l)
                .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("mock ex"));
        verify(mockD, never()).getTime();
    }
```

-------------------The origin implemation of the method `requestTargetDCNFromGSLServer` is like --------------

```
Message requestTargetDCNFromGSLServer(String bizSeqNo, String targetOrgId,String serviceEventId,String scenario,int orgFlag) throws RMBValidationException, RMBIllegalAccessException, GSLInvokeTimeoutException {
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------requestTargetDCNFromGSLServer");//I can only see this log one time
    SysHeader msgHeader = Util.createSysHeader(bizSeqNo,bizSeqNo, SOURCESYSID);
    Destination destination = Util.createSimpleDestination(GSL_SERVICEID,GSL_SCENARIO,GSL_DCN);
    Message reqMessage = Util.createMessage(msgHeader, GSL_APPHEADER,destination, createRequestContent(targetOrgId,serviceEventId,scenario,orgFlag));
    IMessagePublisher synPublisher = getSyncPublisherInstance();
    reqMessage.setTimeToLive(Global.onlyInstance().getGslRequestTimeout());
    Message rspMessage = synPublisher.publish(reqMessage, Global.onlyInstance().getGslRequestTimeout()) ;
    if(rspMessage == null) {
        throw new GSLClient.GSLInvokeTimeoutException("Cannot recieve GSL response at "+ Global.onlyInstance().getGslRequestTimeout()+" ms");
    }else {
        return rspMessage;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide the declaration of `requestTargetDCNFromGSLServer` method? Both in your interface and in class.

Comment: @SergheyBishyr, already shown in the question. And there is no interface, this method is declared in a abstract class `GSLClient`

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking a spy, so you should stick to this order of mocking:

```
    doReturn(buildMockSuccessGSLRespMsg(GSLResponse.ORG_FALG_GSL_INPUT, GSLRetDCN))
    .doThrow(new GSLClient.GSLInvokeTimeoutException("Mock GSL timeout"))
    .when(gslClient).requestTargetDCNFromGSLServer(
             mockGSLBizSeqNo,orgId, eventId, scenario, orgFlag);
```

In your current situation, you are calling a real implementation while mocking, thats why you get the error. When you start the configuration with, what is expected then Mockito can "safeguard" the real method call on a spy inside the `when` method.

Comment: Even though your solution could help, I cannot reproduce the issue in this question. I assume that there is another problem.

Comment: I have try another mock object `Date`, and mock it's `getTime()` mothod but no problem. So for my emergency need , how could I solve my problem when mocking, would you also point out why since I am new to mockito.  Then the reason of the problem should be discussed, I mean why there is no problem when I use the same method for `Date`

Comment: Ok, but i would stick to testing your code, as it might contain some subtle detail. Do you get the same error after my changes?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski, yeah I remove my mock method into   you test code, it works, but I have to mock the second return result, so it is not equivalent, please update your answer for that. And also point out the difference. Thank you!

Comment: There you go, solution added. You just stack up from front not the end

Comment: Just a typo. Can u add the impl of that method? Also when u put a breakpoint inside.. does it stop there at any point during the test?

Comment: You are not calling that method in the GSLSolaceClient constructor are you?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski, sure, no. `GSLSolaceClient ` is very simple that only one another method is implemented.